# Кольми и вельми

Tags: этимология

Если окончание "ми" в словах кольми и вельми это нечто вроде зверьми/зверями, то что тогда означает стоящий в единственном числе "вель"? Не может ли он быть производным от немецкого viel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ст.-сл. велiй (великий), от вель - застывшая форма твор.пад. мн.ч. с оконч.-ми стала наречием вельми - "очень".

От него же вельможа - вель (кратк. прилагательное велик) +*mogja от глагола *mogti (мочь). Вследствие контаминации (смешения) можа и муж сочетание вель можа получило значение "великий муж" - вельможа.

Answer (score 1):

По словарю А. Г. Преображенского можно проследить родственную связь "вельми" с "великим". 
... "велик , велика, велйко; ве
лйкий; стар. велий , велйчие, вели
чина, величавый, великан, велйче
ство, велйчественный, величать,-ся;
вельм стар. очень; веил-, вачь
очень, сильно, весьма: вель-можа,
стар. веле-мудр, веле-гласный.
мр. велык, вельмы, вельхорош.
бр. велизны великий. др. велии, ве
лик.веллиство, величьство, вельми;
вел очень\ веле-: веле-душьный.
веле-муд и др... "
Из чего следует, что данное слово имеет чисто славянские корни.

Answer (score 1):

*Вель* — это «большой», восходит к тому же корню, что и слова *великий*, *воля*, *велеть* и, возможно, *вал*. Первоначально он означал «давить, угнетать», затем «хотеть, выбирать». Как последнее перешло в «большой», мне найти не удалось. Возможно, «желаемый» > «достаточный» > «большой»? Немецкое *viel* восходит к другому индоевропейскому корню со значением «много».